# Flutter: How can I order a Future Listview builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to order the list from less distance to more distance but I calculate the km inside the list and the data comes from a Future builder so Im not sure if I can order this list.

Here is the code

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of(context);

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: null,
    body: FutureBuilder(
      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('uid', isNotEqualTo: userProvider.getUser.uid)
          .get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        return ListView.separated(
          itemCount: (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs.length,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return const Divider(
              color: Colors.grey,
            );
          },
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            String _titleName = (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index]
                    ['name'] +
                ' ' +
                (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index]['lastName'];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                _titleName,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
              ),
              subtitle: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Row(children: [
                  Text(_subtitle,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                ]),
                Row(children: [
                  Text('From' +
                      (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index]['location']
                          ['nameL'] +
                      ' distance'),
                  Text(Haversine.distance(
                          userProvider.getUser.location.latitude,
                          userProvider.getUser.location.longitude,
                          (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index]
                              ['location']['latitude'],
                          (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index]
                              ['location']['longitude']) +
                      ' km')
                ])
              ]),
              onTap() {}
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ));
```

}

Comment: Where is your distance calculating logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pulling the data straight up from Firestore and putting into the FutureBuilder, why don't you move this functionality inside your provided service **UserProvider**, for example (or another service), that way you can encapsulate your data fetching logic and your ordering logic there, as such:

```
class UserProvider {

Future<User> getUserData() {

  List<User> orderedUsers = [];

  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> usersSnapshot = await 
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('uid', isNotEqualTo: userProvider.getUser.uid)
          .get();

   // perform your ordering logic here
   // using the Haversine.distance
   // then populate the orderedUsers collection, 
   // and return it 

   return orderedUsers;

}
```

Then in your FutureBuilder, just do:

```
FutureBuilder(
   future: userProvider.getData(),
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
      // the rest of your rendering logic
   }
)
```

It is good practice to encapsulate your Firebase data fetching inside a provided service, that way you can decouple it from the UI rendering logic. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I'm still learning. Can you please write a little bit of the order logic? I can not get a list of users from database or sort them

Comment: I believe you almost have it. If understand correctly, you want to sort the distances from how far the users are in relation to your current user in descending order, right? Well, create a User model where you capture the name, lastname, lat, long and the distance from your user to the looping user (using the Haversine.distance to calculate it), then insert each of the mapped users to a collection. Then do a sort on the collection by the distance field, and return it in the Future. That should cover it.

Comment: I can't save distance in UserModel because I will have many users and many distances at the same time I think. Cn you please check my answer and help me?